# Github webpage - Error 404 page not found

Tags: github, http-status-code-404, github-pages

I have created a personal website in R studio and committed it to Github.

It is not loading at all, and can not figure out why it is not working.

[image: github_404_error]

The link to my github repository is https://github.com/CPRyan/CPRyan.github.io

I'm sorry I can't provide more details, but I really do not have any clue where to start.

Update:

It's not because I haven't configured the options:
[image: github-pages_green_check]

Update 2: 
https://cpryan.github.io does **not** work but, https://cpryan.github.io/index **does**!

Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this through trial and error.

I'm learning, so my process for creating my repository on github and on my local directory was messy. I still lack the knowledge to explain what the issue was, but here is what solved it.

I pulled from the github repository, merged, and then pushed the whole thing back online with commit and push. I guess this merged the two, "solved the deltas", and integrated it into a functioning set of files. Apologies for the terrible explanation but now it works!

Thanks to @Kevin Kang for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was helpful:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "Trigger rebuild"
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply committing to Github is not enough. You need to configure Github Pages to publish your site.
See [this link](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/#enabling-github-pages-to-publish-your-site-from-master-or-gh-pages).
Also, Index.html should be index.html (not capitalized)

Comment: Yeah, I've done that. It all looks fine, and says "Your site is published at https://cpryan.github.io/ " with a green checkmark. But the link just throws the 404 error.

Comment: https://cpryan.github.io/Index.html works. I just realized you capitalized your filename. Rename it to lowercase index.html :)

Comment: Thanks for your help Kevin! It wasn't the capitalization specifically, but the /Index.html at the end. I feel like it should load without adding "/Index" to the end, but that definitely helped at least get the website loaded and might help me figure out the rest of the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Wait, so normally the DNS will resolve / to /index.html so you don't have to add anything at the end. Did you not change the capitalization? If you have changed it, the github link cpryan.github.io should default to navigating to the (lowercase) index.html page.

Comment: Yeah, even with "Index" changed to "index" for both the .Rmd and the .html the link on its own still doesn't work [https://cpryan.github.io/](https://cpryan.github.io/) whereas [https://cpryan.github.io/index](https://cpryan.github.io/index) does. You clearly know more than I do though so I still don't know how to fix this. :(

Comment: Just checking in, I see it's working now. Congrats! :)